# Can Device Owner app change the device language?

Tags: java, android

I'm building a Device Owner app for Android 8 to Android 11. Before when in system app, we use the hidden API like below:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.android.internal.app.LocalePicker");
Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("updateLocale", Locale.class);
method.invoke(null, Locale.forLanguageTag(localeTag));
```

But this reflection is not available in Device Owner app. It will throw the Security Exception.
So  Could anyone please tell me if there is any method available to change the system language?

Comment: It looks like `DevicePolicyManager` has a locale extra: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#EXTRA_PROVISIONING_LOCALE. You could try provisioning device owner with that. Note that google is not accepting new DPCs on the playstore: https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/build-dpc. Not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for your answer. It seems like that is to set up the locale during the provisioning time of the DO app. Is there any way I can set the locale after provisioning?

Comment: That was all I was able to find. The android-testdpc project: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc does not seem to have this feature and I can't find any android EMMs that list setting the language as a feature of their product. So the answer's probably no.

Comment: @Matt I see. Thanks a lot for your help